# Progress bar is not working above API Level 11

Tags: android, performance, android-progressbar

Progress bar is not showing any progress while recording the audio file .It is working for 2.3.3 version and  3.0 version and when i check for 4.0 version it is not showing any progress.Also when i click stop button it is closing the application.I have **minimum target version as 10**  and **maximum target version as 16** in my application.
        This is the xml code which i have tried.

```
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item android:id="@android:id/background">
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient
                        android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
                        android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
                        android:centerY="0.75"
                        android:endColor="#ff747674"
                        android:angle="270"
                />
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
            <clip>
                <shape>
                    <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                    <gradient
                            android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                            android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                            android:centerY="0.75"
                            android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                            android:angle="270"
                    />
                </shape>
            </clip>
        </item>

        <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
            <clip>
                <shape>
                    <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                    <gradient
                            android:startColor="#ffffd300"
                            android:centerColor="#ffffb600"
                            android:centerY="0.75"
                            android:endColor="#ffffcb00"
                            android:angle="270"
                    />
                </shape>
            </clip>
        </item>

    </layer-list>
```

My Recording Activity is as follows

```
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.recording);
            record = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.record);
            time = (Chronometer) this.findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
            OUTPUT_FILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/recorder.mp3";
            recordSeeker = (ProgressBar) this.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(record.getText().equals("Record")){
                    record.setText("Stop");
                    try {
                        start();
                    }
                    catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    }
                    else{
                    record.setText("Record");   
                    stop(); 
                    }
                }

                private void start() throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
                        ditchRecorder();
                        time.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                        time.start();
                        File f = new File(OUTPUT_FILE);
                        if(f.exists())
                            f.delete();
                        recordSeeker.setProgress(0);
                        recordSeeker.setMax(100);
                        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                        recorder = new AudioRecorder("/path");
                        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(OUTPUT_FILE);
                        mediaRecorder.prepare();
                        mediaRecorder.start();
                        task = new BackgroundAsyncTask(activity, record, myProgress,
                                recordSeeker);
                        task.execute();
                }
                private void ditchRecorder() {
                    if(mediaRecorder != null)
                        mediaRecorder.release();
                }
                private void stop() {
                if(mediaRecorder!= null){
                        time.stop();
                        mediaRecorder.stop();
                }
                }   
            }
            );
            }
```

BackgroundAsync task class is follow below:

```
public class BackgroundAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    Activity activity;
    Button playing;
    int myProgress;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    String reviewdetails;

     BackgroundAsyncTask(Activity act, Button playing, int myProgress,
            ProgressBar progressBar) {
        activity = act;
        this.playing = playing;
        this.myProgress = myProgress;
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(activity, "onPostExecute", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        playing.setText("Stop");
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Completed asynk", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Toast.makeText(activity, "onPreExecute", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        myProgress = 0;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (myProgress < 1800) {
            myProgress++;
            publishProgress(myProgress);
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
            if (isCancelled())
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);

    }
```

Comment: And `BackgroundAsyncTask` does what? Please paste the code. Thanks

Comment: Yes i will paste that

Comment: So your max progress is 100, but in the while you have <1800 - why is thaT?

Comment: As a sidenote, unless you have a very specific reason, you needn't/shouldn't set a maximum target version.

Comment: I have set 2 hours as the maximum duration for the recording time.so i have set while(my progress<1800)

Comment: Then why do you `recordSeeker.setMax(100)`?